# whats the difference between map.resources and map.resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi Could any one let me know the difference.

Thanks in Advance-- Vam.

Answer (score 1):

`resource` will create a singluar resource i.e. all the routes of `resources` but without index.

It's useful for things like "account".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation from the official Ruby on Rails guides:

- [Resource Routing: the Rails Default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)
- [Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Answer (score 0):

One is plural, one is singular.
Good example on 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Basically if your representing something which has more than one possible URL - i.e. you can look up multiple different books or authors, use map.resources. If you want to just look up a singular resource. For example the current user or the one and only Admin page, use map.resource